How To Generate Word Level Subtitles For Audio Via Whisper?
I have a audio file and the transcript for it. How do I generate word level subtitles using whisper.
I saw the implementation on this pull request, but I couldn't find how to use it in the documentation.
I have seen a similar library whisperX but it's written in Python and it works on GPU.
